# After deploying with Firebase, I deleted my authentication account and Firestore stopped working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

After deploying with Firebase, I deleted my authentication account and Firestore stopped working.

It says:

> Failure to update security rules causes client requests to be denied in the Cloud Firestore database.

I made the following changes, but they did not solve the problem.

```
rules_version = '2';   service cloud.firestore {
       match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
        allow delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      }
      match /{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if true;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What code is raising that error? Please edit your question to include that. You might also want to read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as following the guidance in there drastically increases the chances that someone can help.

Comment: why did you delete your account?

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. Perhaps the error above has nothing to do with it, just that the daily limit has been reached.
Please help me again if it is not fixed tomorrow.